# Como reduzir os campos de retorno do Page em uma API?

Tags: java, api, spring

Estou implementando paginação em alguns endpoints da minha API e o retorno é um `Page`. Esse objeto retorna muitos argumentos, existe alguma forma de eliminar alguns deles?

**O repository extends JpaRepository**

**SERVICE**

```
@Autowired
ClienteRepositoy clienteRepositoy;

public List<Cliente> findAllList() {
    return clienteRepositoy.findAll();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@Autowired
ServiceCliente serviceCliente;

@GetMapping("/clientes")
public Page<Cliente> getClientes() {
    List<Cliente> clientes = serviceCliente.findAllList();
    return new PageImpl<>(convertToDto(clientes), PageRequest.of(0, 10), clientes.size());
}
```

**RETORNO JSON**

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "TESTE AUTOMATICO"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 7,
    "last": true,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 7,
    "empty": false
}
```

Gostaria de remover informações como o objeto pageable inteiro, por exemplo:

```
"pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma que você está fazendo não é a ideal: você busca todos e aí sim pagina eles. Ao meu ver o certo seria buscar todos paginado: o `findAll` do spring pode receber um `Peageable` como parametro. Dessa forma você não retornaria um `PageImpl<>`, você teria de retorno do seu método do service um Page; 
Dessa forma, tendo uma lista de Page, você pode retornar apenas o conteúdo dessa lista (uma lista de clientes realmente): `return clientes.getContent()`.
Espero ter sido claro. Abraço!

Comment: Foi bem claro sim. Eu retorno uma lista de clientes e faço um processamento com essa lista antes de retornar, bem como converte-los em DTO para não expor minha entidade diretamente. Se eu usar o `findAll(Pageable)` vou ter que trabalhar com as Pages e não com as entidades.

Comment: E o retorno acaba sendo o mesmo do que a forma com que estou fazendo :/